# ScrollView like in Google+ app

Tags: android, scrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Google achieve animated posts in their G+ app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410187/how-does-google-achieve-animated-posts-in-their-g-app)

I want to make the exact same ScrollView like it is in Google plus app when you open a post with an image. That means the ScrollView starts in the middle of the screen and when users drags it up it animates scrolling to the top of the screen and when user drags it down it jumps to the starting position in the middle of the screen.

Any ideas how to achieve this?
So far I've came up with a scrollview that has a transparent view on the top and the content is below but I haven't figured out how to make it to dock either to the top of teh screen or to the starting position.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like it's a `ScrollView` inside of some kind of a [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

EDIT: just to improve on my own answer, I ran `HierarchyViewer` on the Activity you've requested. Here is the [View tree PNG file](http://lh.rs/A92wShX4Cdkh) and the [Photoshop file with all the splitted layers](http://lh.rs/eO6c5u1vPaKX), as produced by HierarchyViewer.

Quick analysis: to do their job, they use a parent `RelativeLayout` (ID list_parent) that fills the whole available space and contains a custom `ExpandableScrollView` (ID list_expander) that can likely increase its height and expand just like a `SlidingDrawer` would (plus animations and stuff). This contains, in turn, a `StreamOneUpListView` (ID list), that itself contains the post information's `StreamOneUpActivityView`, a `StreamOneUpCommentCountView`, and the various comments' `StreamOneUpCommentView`s. It's noteworthy that if the `StreamOneUpListView` doesn't contain comments, or there aren't enough to cover the whole available height, it will have an empty `StreamOneUpLeftoverView` that serves as whitespace and fills it.

So... yes, it might be a bit tricky to implement this sorta stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you. It's from Roman Nurik, one of the Google Android Developer Advocates.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I want. I want something that if user drags it up, it scrolls to the top after certain threshold - just like the SlidingDrawer does.